# Save value from array to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

So, I'm getting JSON data, which I save to a variable and which is an array.

```
var my_data
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/geo', function(data){
 my_data = data;
 console.log(my_data);
});
```

in console I have this:

```
Object {
  city: "Krasnoyarsk",
  country: "RU",
  ip: "212.119.233.96",
  loc: "56.0184,92.8672",
  postal: "660000",
  region: "Krasnoyarskiy Kray"
}
```

but the only thing I need from this array is the name of the city. I tried the following:

```
var my_city = my_data.filter(function (filt) {
  return filt.city;});
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

So, my question is: am I trying to do this in a right way and something is just not right OR is this code completely wrong?

Comment: Have you try just var my_city=my_data.city;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access properties of an `Object` simply by using `dot-notation` like:

```
var myCity = my_data.city;
```

This only works for properties which fulfill the naming rules for variables, which means something like `{ "street-and-city": '...' }` can't be accessed by using `dot-notation`. You have to access these properties like this:

```
var myStreetAndCity = my_data["street-and-city"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The returned object is an object, it's not array. So there is no need to use `.filter` here. Just do

```
console.log(my_data.city);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone! now I realized I went too deep

```
var my_data
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/geo', function(data){
 my_data = data;
 console.log(my_data.city);
});

var my_city = my_data.city;
```

works fine